# change function param value inside function in C

Tags: c, function, param

Stupid question, is it a good way to change value of function parameter inside the function or create another variable to hold it, which one is better? 
eg :

```
s16 functionA(s16 sum) {
u8 addy = 5; 
sum += addy; 
return sum;
}
```

OR

```
s16 functionA(s16 origin) {
u8 addy = 5; 
s16 sum = origin + addy; 
return sum;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to write to the parameter, and *might* even be better performance-wise depending on how clever the compiler is.

On the other hand, your example could also be written as:

```
s16 functionA(s16 sum)
{
  const u8 addy = 5; /* Assuming this is more complex in reality. */
  return sum + addy;
}
```

There's no point in assigning to `sum` and then returning it, the two statements can be combined.

Answer (score 0):

OR

```
s16 functionA(s16 origin) {
    u8 addy = 5;
    return origin + addy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the second one doesn't improve readability, I would choose the first one.

Moreover, it saves 2 bytes on the stack, which can be good in a embedded environment (but it's very likely that the compiler will optimize it).